# upload a xls file with postman to a RESTapi made with node/express

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multer

In node a can make something like this with and excel file in my directory.

```
  app.post('/api/xlstojson', function(req, res) {   
    var workbook = XLSX.readFile('tc2.xls');
    var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
    res.json(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]));
});
```

I want to test file uploading with postman.  There I select `POST`, `form-data`, in `key` I select file instead of text and then in `value` I upload the tc2.xls file.

In my code I have something like this

```
app.post('/api/xlstojson', function(req, res) { 
    var workbook = XLSX.readFile(req.body.file);
    var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
    res.json(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]));
});
```

But I get `TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer`. How should I modify my code to make this work?

Update:

I have been trying with multer, but the file does not appear in the folder

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({ 
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1])
    }
});
var upload = multer({ //multer settings
                storage: storage
            }).single('file');
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
             res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
             return;
        }
         res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer

You're getting this error because you're not passing the file location. For this to work, you need to pass the location of the file within the `upload/` folder

```
'use strict';

const XLSX = require('xlsx');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var datetimestamp = Date.now();
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1]);
  }
});
var upload = multer({ //multer settings
  storage: storage
});

function validate(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.send({
      errors: {
        message: 'file cant be empty'
      }
    });
  }
  next();
}

app.post('/api/xlstojson', upload.single('file'), validate, function (req, res) {
  const fileLocation = req.file.path;
  console.log(fileLocation); // logs uploads/file-1541675389394.xls
  var workbook = XLSX.readFile(fileLocation);
  var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
  return res.json({
    json: XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]])
  });
});
```

You need to upload the xls file from postman

[image: postman xls upload]